# Does Google Drive drive.file scope allow app to download files it uploaded prior to an app uninstall/reinstall?

Tags: google-drive-api

For Google Drive *drive.file* scope, Google's docs state:

`Per-file access to files created or opened by the app. File authorization is granted on a per-user basis and is revoked when the user deauthorizes the app.`

From this, I'd expect that files my app uploads to Google Drive would remain available for download to the app even if the app was subsequently deinstalled and reinstalled. However that is not my experience. In a test app, if I upload a text file I can then successfully download it immediately. However if I reinstall my app and just download the file, the contents are empty.

Is this expected, or is there an issue with my code below? It uses Google Drive .NET Rest API (Xamarin Forms / Android) and is based on https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179592/google-drive-rest-api-in-xamarin-android

```
public class DriveServiceHelper
{
    private DriveService driveService;
    public DriveServiceHelper ( DriveService driveService )
    {
        this.driveService = driveService;
    }

    public async Task<string> CreateTextFile ()
    // Returns Id of text file
    {
        File metadata = new File ()
        {
            Parents = new List<string>() { "root" },
            MimeType = "text/plain",
            Name = "Test.txt"
        };

       var googleFile =await this.driveService.Files.Create ( metadata ).ExecuteAsync ();
        if ( googleFile == null )
        {
            throw new System.IO.IOException ( "Null result when requesting text file creation." );
        }
        return googleFile.Id;
    }
    
    public async Task<FileData> ReadTextFile ( string fileId )
    // Returns content of given text file
    {
        FileData data = new FileData ();

        try
        { 
            var metadata = await driveService.Files.Get ( fileId ).ExecuteAsync ();
            data.Name = metadata.Name;
            using ( System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream()  )
            {
                await driveService.Files.Get( fileId ).DownloadAsync( memoryStream );
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                using ( System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader( memoryStream, Encoding.Default ) )
                    data.Content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            //await Utility.WriteLogFileAsync ( T.Exception, ex.AsString () );
            throw new Exception ( "In DriveServiceHelper.ReadTextFile " + ex.ToString (), ex.InnerException );
        }

        return data;
    }

    public async Task WriteTextFile ( string fileId, string filename, string content )
    // Saves given content to Google Drive
    {
        try
        { 
            File metadata = new File ()
            {
                Name= filename
            };
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes ( content );
            await driveService.Files.Update ( metadata, fileId, new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray), "text/plain").UploadAsync ();
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            //await Utility.WriteLogFileAsync ( T.Exception, ex.AsString () );
            throw new Exception ( "In DriveServiceHelper.WriteTextFile " + ex.ToString (), ex.InnerException );
        }
    }
}

public class FileData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

/////

```
    DriveServiceHelper helper = new DriveServiceHelper ( driveService );
    string id = await helper.CreateTextFile ();
    //await helper.WriteTextFile ( id, "Test.txt", "Test save content" ); // When this line is removed, can't read the file
    FileData content = await helper.ReadTextFile ( id );
```

Comment: So from what I understand you are no longer able to access the same file after deleting the app? Is the user logging in the same? Are you using the same id to redownload the file?

Comment: Thanks, @Raserhin. I've switched to using Dropbox as I hadn't been able to progress. I found that Dropbox's model is more suitable for my app as it offers a persistent per-app folder